# AWS Causes in Dyanmo for ConditionalCheckFailedException?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have about 30 instances running and submitting data to dynamo, but in my logs, I'm getting a ton of `ConditionalCheckFailedException` failure messages. The weird thing is, I'm not saving with any conditional check, unless I'm missing something:

```
  private void save(DynamoObject myObject) {
    try {
      mapper.save(model);
    } catch (ConditionalCheckFailedException e) {
       // metrics and logging
    } catch (Exception e) {
       // metrics and logging
    }
```

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using [DynamoDBMapper](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBMapper.html) and specifically `@DynamoDBVersionAttribute` somewhere and your put item failure is related to the mapper's [optimistic locking](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBMapper.OptimisticLocking.html) strategy. The item version on the server is different to that on the client side because of another write to that item, so DynamoDB rejects the put.

You'll need to reconcile the item differences client-side and re-submit.